# How to determine if a method is called from outside of an object or inside?

Tags: php

How do I determine if a method is called from outside of an object or from inside?

For Example:

```
class Example{


   public function Foo(){
      $this->Bar();      
   }


   public function Bar(){
      if(this_function_was_called_from_outside_the_object){
         echo 'I see you\'re an outsider!' // this method was invoked from outside the object.
      }else{
         echo 'I\'m talking to myself again.'; // this method was invoked from another method in this object.
      }
   }
}

$oExample = new Example();
$oExample->Foo(); // I\'m talking to myself again.
$oExample->Bar(); // I see you\'re an outsider!
```

Comment: You should never need to do that. Explain what problem you believe will be solved if you do it so that we can help you with that instead.

Comment: You don't. And the reason you don't is because you don't have to. If there exists something that lead you to conclude that you have to know who and where called the function, then you can be 100% that you chose the wrong path.

Comment: I am aware that there may be other solutions, but those solutions, such as having multiple copies of the function, are less elegant than simply switching based on whether the caller is or is not `$this`. If this cannot be done, then the answer to the question should be "PHP has no way to detect this".

Comment: Further, I find it incredibly arrogant that some would presume, without seeing any of the application code, that the architecture of the application is flawed, or that I am ignorant of PHP and/or OO programing standards. Debating application architectural decisions is beyond the scope of (and not relevant to) this question. Please see http://www.shlomifish.org/philosophy/computers/web/use-qmail-instead/. I would not have asked if I did not have a good reason for asking.

Answer (score 0):

In the method you call, throw and catch immediatly an exception, like this :

```
public function test()
{
    try 
    {
        throw new Exception("My Exception");
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        //check the stack trace at desired level
        //print_r($e->getTrace());
    }

    //Your code here
}
```

In the catch block, you can browse the stack trace and see who called the method.
After this try/catch block, just put your normal code.

Comment: You could also use `debug_backtrace()` to get this information, but the trace only shows one object at all levels- There doesn't seem to be any information that indicates the object instance that called the function, which could be compared to $this.

Answer (score -2):

use get_called_class() function of php

It will return the class name. Will return FALSE if called from outside a class.

Comment: This is not even close to what `get_called_class` does.